# How to display SQL Syntax error from a Excel VBA Userform

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, odbc

I would like to ask for some help, here's the context: I'm using an Excel Workbook that is connected to my SQL Server with ODBC, so the user can use it to make some queries using some macros + buttons.

He asked me if it's possible to create an interface between the Excel and the SQL Server, like if you're using the DBMS, showing a userform to type the query and if you get some syntax error, it will be showed to you).

Here's my problem : I've created successfully the interface, but I cannot display the Syntax Error. It appears only the message : "Run Time Error '1004' SQL Syntax Error".

It's possible to show the exactly message like if you're using the DBMS?

---

To make it easier to understand, here's my code :

```
Function Query(SQL As String)

On Error GoTo Err_handler

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "ODBC;DSN=mydb;Description=test;UID=test;PWD=test;APP=Microsoft Office 2003;WSID=test123" _
        , Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .CommandText = (SQL)
        .Name = "test"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    Exit Function

Err_handler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description

End Function
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think that you need to post your code for more information. Take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for this site.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for your suggestion, I've edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use something like the `ActiveX Data Objects` library (`ADODB`) so you can get specific connection information.  Therefore, when you run the code, the SQL will raise an error on the ADO object, but then the `Err` object will contain SQL-specific error information bubbled up from the database.

You need to add a `Reference` to `ActiveX Data Objects` in your VBA project.  Once you have done that, then try this:-

```
Function MyQuery(SQL As String)

  Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
  Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
  Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

  On Error GoTo Err_handler

  'DB Connection Object
  Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
  cn.Open "DSN=mydb;Description=test;UID=test;PWD=test;APP=Microsoft Office 2003;WSID=test123"

  'SQL Command Object
  Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
  cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
  cmd.CommandType = adCmdText
  cmd.CommandText = SQL

  'Recordset Object to contain results
  Set rs = cmd.Execute

  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=rs, Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Name = "test"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With

MyQueryx:

  'Clean up - close connections and destroy objects
  If Not rs Is Nothing Then
    If rs.State = ADODB.adStateOpen Then
      rs.Close
    End If
    Set rs = Nothing
  End If

  If Not cmd Is Nothing Then
    Set cmd.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
  End If

  If Not cn Is Nothing Then
    If cn.State = ADODB.adStateOpen Then
      cn.Close
    End If
    Set cn = Nothing
  End If

  Exit Function

Err_handler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  'Goto to the function exit to clean up
  GoTo MyQueryx

End Function
```

Comment: I think that this is not a right answer for the question. Please read again. He know the error, he want to shown the error message which is come from database.

Comment: It is the right answer.  The error will be raised on the `RecordSet` object and therefore, the `Err` object will bubble up the SQL error in full.

Comment: Hi joehanna, thanks for your answer. I've tried to add your code to my, but now I got this error message : Data source name not found and no default driver specified

The strange part is that with the same code used in the connection, I can connect in the 'old way' normally. Do you know if there's anything missing?

And just for you to know, this part of the code (cn.close) it's getting an error message code 3004.

  If Not cn Is Nothing Then
    If cn.State <> ADODB.adStateOpen Then
      cn.Close
    End If
    Set cn = Nothing
  End If

Comment: This will be an incompatibility of the connection string with `ADODB.Connection`.  Try removing `ODBC;` from the connection string like so:-  `cn.Open "DSN=mydb;Description=test;UID=test;PWD=test;APP=Microsoft Office 2003;WSID=test123"`.  Let me know how you get on.

Comment: I've changed and I could execute the SQL Query normally, so I created this one just for test "select * from sys.tables order b name" (as you can see, the error is in the "b", it should be "by".

When I run the macro, still gaves me only the error 1004, not showing exactly what's wrong. Got it?

Comment: Did you copy/paste my code into your project?  I have retested it and it works for me using your sample SQL.  I just found a tiny bug in my code when closing the recordset and connections (`<>` should be `=`) but that shouldn't cause you a problem.

Comment: Yes joehanna, just copied and paste... What's the library that you selected? (maybe its the version... )

Comment: I used `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library"

Comment: I've changed the activex data object to 2.8 but the problem persists. I dont know what could be wrong... :(

Comment: Joehanna, I've changed the order of priority of the libraries and now its working! :D

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There was 4 selected, then I've selected the ActiveX and move it to the top.
Now I've realized something really weird, when I try to make some query (that have results), a message appears saying that I have an error with my object. When I create a fake query (that results nothing), it shows the columns normally. Any ideia? (Oh my gosh, how this could be so complicated hahaha)

Comment: I suggest you start a new question for a new problem.  This one is exhausted :-)